# Confirm & alert not firing in my Ajax success function

Tags: javascript, ajax, alert, confirm

I have a function that displays a table from an Ajax request :

```
function loadExternalBenefits() {
    var id_project = $('input[name=id_project]').val();
    $.ajax({
        url : '/projects/getExternalBenefits',
        method : 'POST',
        data : {'fk_project' : id_project, 'ajax' : true},
        success : function(result) {
            $('#panel-external-benefits').find('.right').first().html(result);

            $('.delete_external_benefits').on('click', function() {
                if(confirm("Voulez-vous vraiment supprimer cette ligne ?")) {
                    console.log('ok');
                    var id_item = $(this).data('id');
                    deleteExternalBenefits(id_item);
                } else {
                    console.log('ko');
                }
                return false;
            });
        },
    });
}
```

If I do a "console.log('something')" in the success function, it works, but I cannot do an alert or a confirm. Problem is I have a trigger on click that have to fire a confirm window. It systematicly displays the console.log "ko", without even displaying the dialog.

Of course, I have no error in my console and I couldn't find a solution on the Internet because most of the time, it's an issue of Ajax returning an error (not a success).

Do you have an idea ?

@el_tomato : Here is the console.log(result)

```
<table class="classic-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Libellé</th>
            <th>Quantité</th>
            <th>Prix d'achat</th>
            <th>Coeff.</th>
            <th>Prix total</th>
            <th>Marge</th>            
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Une prestation externe</td>
            <td class="align-center">3</td>
            <td class="price align-right">150,00 €</td>
            <td class="price align-right">1.2</td>
            <td class="price align-right">540,00 €</td>
            <td class="price align-right">90,00 €</td>
            <td><button class="delete_external_benefits delete" data-id="24">x</button></td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You're attaching a click handler within an ajax `success` callback - that makes very little sense. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: JQuery's `.on()` method is used to register event handlers to an element so your click function won't execute in the success callback of the ajax request

Comment: Can you try to put a  `console.log(result)` inside the `success` function and share what get printed?

Comment: @Jamiec : I put my click handler here because the trigger is in the table thrown in the success (result). 
Will.Harris : I tried using just .click() and it doesn't work too.

Comment: @el_tomato : I can, but it has no interest, it's just a HTML table. I edited the subject.

Comment: Given your output and your handler, this problem cannot be reproduced - the confirm (and an alert) show up just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/54Luupqx/

Comment: if you want to trigger the `.click()` event of an element in the success callback look at using JQuery's `.trigger()` method. If not then take your `if (confirm('')) { }` code out of the `click()` event and run it on its own

Comment: So, I found the issue... What a shame. The problem was my browser that has deactivated the alert pop-ups. So, it works in an other. Somehow, it reassures me because it was very very weird. Thank's to all of you.

Answer (score 0):

Put this inside `$(document).ready()`,

```
$(document.body).on("click", ".delete_external_benefits", function(e) {
    if(confirm("Voulez-vous vraiment supprimer cette ligne ?")) {
        console.log('ok');
        var id_item = $(this).data('id');
        deleteExternalBenefits(id_item);
    } else {
        console.log('ko');
    }
    return false;
});
```

And in place of the above code, write

```
$('.delete_external_benefits').trigger("click");
```

I hope that should work

Comment: The OP stated that this was element was loaded dynamically in the ajax success, this will not work!

Comment: Good one - you could have delegated to `#panel-external-benefits` which is where the OP is puttin gthe new content instead of `document.body`.

Comment: Thanks, that can be done too. But I prefer using `document.body` because I may change the `id` or `class` I am delegating in future. So that would stop my running code.

Comment: And slow it down, considerably ;)